# How to format date using jquery from the output

Tags: jquery, date-format

I'm trying to display date format as I wanted but none of the solutions did not work for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var html = '';
  var startDate = '07/04/2017';
  var chunks = startDate.split('/');
  var startformattedDate = chunks[1] + '-' + chunks[0] + '-' + chunks[2];

  var endDate = '15/04/2017';
  var chunks1 = endDate.split('/');
  var endformattedDate = chunks1[1] + '-' + chunks1[0] + '-' + chunks1[2];

  var start = new Date(startformattedDate);
  var end = new Date(endformattedDate);
  var data = [];

  while (start <= end) {
    data.push(new Date(start));
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + data[i] + '</td></tr>';
  }
  $('.Dates').append(html);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="Dates">
</table>
```

I want to display the date either of below formats. How do I do that?

`Fri Apr 07 2017` or `Fri 7th Apr 2017`

I tried using below formats but none of them does not match my desired output

```
new Date().toISOString()

new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

new Date().toISOString().replace('-', '/').split('T')[0].replace('-', '/');

new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0]
```

Any suggestions, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `new Date().toString().substring(0,15)`

`new Date().toString()` will return a format like this: `Tue Aug 01 2017 08:14:20 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)`

Then by adding `.substring(0,15)` we can take this part out `Tue Aug 01 2017`

```js
console.log(new Date().toString().substring(0,15))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is your code and working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var html = '';
  var startDate = '07/04/2017';
  var chunks = startDate.split('/');
  var startformattedDate = chunks[1] + '-' + chunks[0] + '-' + chunks[2];

  var endDate = '15/04/2017';
  var chunks1 = endDate.split('/');
  var endformattedDate = chunks1[1] + '-' + chunks1[0] + '-' + chunks1[2];

  var start = new Date(startformattedDate);
  var end = new Date(endformattedDate);
  var data = [];

  while (start <= end) {
    data.push(new Date(start));
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + data[i].toString().substring(0,15) + '</td></tr>';
  }
  $('.Dates').append(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="Dates">
</table>
```

Comment: Oops. Same as mine and I didn't saw this while I was coding it in the code-editor. Difference of 30 seconds :)

Comment: @06011991 No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` to get your required date format:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var html = '';
  var startDate = '07/04/2017';
  var chunks = startDate.split('/');
  var startformattedDate = chunks[1] + '-' + chunks[0] + '-' + chunks[2];

  var endDate = '15/04/2017';
  var chunks1 = endDate.split('/');
  var endformattedDate = chunks1[1] + '-' + chunks1[0] + '-' + chunks1[2];

  var start = new Date(startformattedDate);
  var end = new Date(endformattedDate);
  var data = [];

  while (start <= end) {
    data.push(new Date(start));
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    html += '<tr><td>' + data[i].toString().substring(0, 15) + '</td></tr>';
  }
  $('.Dates').append(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="Dates">
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var formateJsonDateToSimpleDateFormate=function(jsondate){
var datePart=jsondate.split('T')[0];
datePart=datePart.substring(0,10);
var dateNew=datePart.split('-');
var date=dateNew[2]+'/'+dateNew[1]+'/'+dateNew[0];
return date;
}
```

I did this. and it worked for me.
 and

```
 var formateJsonDateToSimpleDateFormate=function(jsondate){
  var d=new Date(parseInt(jsondate.slice(6,-2)));
 var hour=d.getHours()==0?12:(d.getHours()>12?d.getHours()-12:d.getHours());
var min=d.getMinutes<10?'0'+d.getMinutes():d.getMinutes();
var ampm=d.getHours()<12?'AM':'PM';
hour=hour<10?'0'+hour:hour;
var time=hour+':'+min+' '+ampm;
var date=d.getDate()+'-'+getMonthNameInShortForm(1+d.getMonth())+'-'d.getFullYear()+ " "+time;
return date;
```

}

```
var getMonthNameInShortForm=function(monthNumber){
var months=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
return months[monthNumber+1];
}
```

Comment: you should split by "/" and append with "-"

Answer (score 0):

Insted of appending `data[i]` in loop you can use it like

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   html += '<tr><td>' + data[i].toString().split(" 00")[0] + '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats), then you may do so with the following:

```
var formatted_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('D M dd yy', new Date());
// Fri Apr 07 2017

var formatted_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('D M dth yy', new Date());
// Fri Apr 7th 2017
```

Note: for the second one, it doesn't work well with 1st, 2nd, 3rd... because it will output 1th, 2th, 3th, but you can try creating an if condition before returning a format.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use jquery-dateFormat without jQuery. You just need to import
>   the dateFormat.js above and instead of formatting with $.format(...)
>   you should use DateFormat.format('D M dth yy').

[For more check the document..](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-dateformat)